# HTML Color Input "oninput" event behaving differently on Chrome on Windows

Tags: javascript, html

On firefox, the `oninput` event of a color type input is fired while the OS color picker window is opened, everytime the user switches a color.

Now, on chrome it works exactly as the `onchange` event, it only fires if the actual color changes after pressing ok on the color picker window.

Is there a way to get the expected behavior on chrome? Is this a bug or a implementation choice?

Also, is there an event that fires even if the user doesn't change the color but only opens the color picker and presses ok? A `onclick` wouldn't be ideal as that would also trigger if the user presses cancel.

```js
const colorInput = document.getElementById('color');
color.oninput = evt => {
  console.log('oninput');
}
```

```html
<input id="color" type="color">
```

Edit : It seems that chrome and edge behave the same.

Comment: I get oninput fired on any click unless the click is on the same colour as previous. Chrome 72 OSX

Comment: Using Chrome on Mac, I get `onInput` fired every time I change the colour.

Comment: It's probably related to windows as the box is from the OS, edited the title

Comment: By the way, there is an [issue in chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=947136), presumably
based on this question.

Comment: @wrager yes! I made it

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is a Windows limitation. The [`ChooseColor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646912(v=vs.85).aspx) function is responsible for that dialog and it only outputs the color information when the user closes the dialog.

If you want the user to be able to change colors live, consider using a library like [jscolor](http://jscolor.com/).

Comment: This doesn't explain why it works in Firefox running on Windows, it seems to also use the same color swatch